# WinError 10060 : while trying to download NASDAQ_ITCH50 gz file

Tags: python

I've tried the below to download the NASDAQ ITCH file but was met with the [WinError 10060]:

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

urlretrieve('ftp://emi.nasdaq.com/ITCH/Nasdaq ITCH/', '10302019.NASDAQ_ITCH50.gz')
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in ftp_open(self, req)
   1562         try:
-> 1563             fw = self.connect_ftp(user, passwd, host, port, dirs, req.timeout)
   1564             type = file and 'I' or 'D'

~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in connect_ftp(self, user, passwd, host, port, dirs, timeout)
   1583     def connect_ftp(self, user, passwd, host, port, dirs, timeout):
-> 1584         return ftpwrapper(user, passwd, host, port, dirs, timeout,
   1585                           persistent=False)

~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in __init__(self, user, passwd, host, port, dirs, timeout, persistent)
   2404         try:
-> 2405             self.init()
   2406         except:

~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in init(self)
   2413         self.ftp = ftplib.FTP()
-> 2414         self.ftp.connect(self.host, self.port, self.timeout)
   2415         self.ftp.login(self.user, self.passwd)

~\anaconda3\lib\ftplib.py in connect(self, host, port, timeout, source_address)
    157         sys.audit("ftplib.connect", self, self.host, self.port)
--> 158         self.sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout,
    159                                              source_address=self.source_address)

~\anaconda3\lib\socket.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
    843         try:
--> 844             raise err
    845         finally:

~\anaconda3\lib\socket.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
    831                 sock.bind(source_address)
--> 832             sock.connect(sa)
    833             # Break explicitly a reference cycle

TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

I've tried to google about it and some say it's a proxy issue, but can anyone help enlighten the right problem that I'm having? Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

from urllib.request import urlretrieve

urlretrieve('https://emi.nasdaq.com/ITCH/Nasdaq%20ITCH/', '10302019.NASDAQ_ITCH50.gz')

The above worked, just by changing ftp to https and 'Nasdaq ITCH' changed to 'Nasdaq%20ITCH/'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).